# Can I browse the Mac App Store without Snow Leopard?

Tags: mac-appstore

I understand that Snow Leopard is required to install the Mac App Store and actually install apps. But is it possible to browse the store on the web the way you can with the [iTunes Store](http://itunes.apple.com/uk/browse)?

Comment: Ah, the restrictments of Apple... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to *browse* the App Store. But if you have a link, such as [this one](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/delicious-library-2/id403067185?mt=12), then you can view the app description in your browser.

Comment: This is no longer true as there are [third parties providing access](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/228557/4870).

Answer (score 10):

It's possible to browse the Mac App Store in your browser. Here is the link to do so:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/mac/id39?mt=12

Comment: Does not provide all the features for browsing (e.g. I couldn't find how to see New & Noteworthy apps), but still quite useful. I suspect Apple built it primarily for SEO.

Comment: It's quite useful too if your Apple account is not from the US but you'd rather browse the original/American version of the Mac App Store, rather than a localized one.

Answer (score 4):

The need of 10.6 is clearly stated on Apple website [here](http://www.apple.com/mac/app-store/). Click then on `Get the Mac App Store. See How` button.

You then see *"The Mac App Store is available as a free software update for Mac computers running Mac OS X v10.6 or later. If you have an earlier version of Mac OS X, you will need to upgrade to Mac OS X Snow Leopard."*

Answer (score 1):

You can effectively search the App Store by using the Google `site` keyword:

Examples:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=site:itunes.apple.com+ssh
- https://www.google.com/search?q=site:itunes.apple.com+ebooks
- https://www.google.com/search?q=site:itunes.apple.com+sync

If you use [Fetch search](http://fetch.yellosoft.us/) and enter the command "app *query*", Fetch will return results from the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

It **is possible** to *browse* the Mac App Store, although not directly.

A number of sites scrape Mac App Store data and provide a way to search and go through app descriptions via a web browser. Some examples are:

- [AppShopper](http://appshopper.com/mac/)
- [App Annie](https://www.appannie.com) – free registration required.